# Multiple domain nameserver registrations

Tags: networking, dns, domain, nameserver

I registered a domain on `dot.tk` (domain registration company for `.tk`) and forwarded it to my website hosted elsewhere. This resulted in A record being created pointing to my website's (static) IP address. It seems `dot.tk` uses nameserver `NS01.FREENOM.COM`.

I then accidentally did the same on my hosting provider's website, which also resulted in the creation of an A record, pointing to the same IP address. Of course, my hosting company has its own nameserver.

Is this ok or should I delete / fix one of these records? How would the internet know which of the two A records is correct (if let's say I accidentally used different IP addresses for them)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How would the internet know which of the two A records is correct (if let's say I accidentally used different IP addresses for them)?

Both records are on different DNS servers. "The internet" doesn't *automatically* see both of them at once; instead, clients only look at the domain's designated nameservers.

The ultimate authority here is your TLD's registry which keeps `NS` records pointing to each domain's nameservers, and your domain's registrar which *usually* lets you update that information. (Most registrars allow you to choose custom nameservers, or the registrar's "managed" ones.)

For example, to use the registrar's own site as an example: According to the `tk.` TLD's nameservers, the domain `dot.tk.` is further delegated to the following four nameservers:

```
$ dig dot.tk. ns @a.ns.tk.

dot.tk.         7151    IN  NS  ns1.dns.tk.
dot.tk.         7151    IN  NS  ns4.dns.tk.
dot.tk.         7151    IN  NS  ns2.dns.tk.
dot.tk.         7151    IN  NS  ns3.dns.tk.
```

Therefore when you look up `A` records for `dot.tk.`, the query always ends up at one of those four servers.

If someone else tried to configure *their* DNS server to host a fake version of the same domain, it wouldn't go anywhere beyond that server – it's not in the NS records kept by the registry, so nobody would look there.

Comment: Thx. So the only reason my hosting provider offered to include the DNS information is if I didn't want to use my registration company's name servers, in which case I'd tell it to use a different NS right? And there's no real difference about which name servers to use?

Comment: It doesn't matter much – you choose based on reliability and features which matter to you. For example (assuming you're choosing between web-managed ones), you might compare what record types are supported (e.g. if you need SRV or NAPTR); whether DNSSEC is supported or not; whether the nameserver allows you to import an existing zone from another NS or requires adding everything by hand.